# How do you ignore empty array in python numpy

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have three list, which has fruit name, color and amount
and it is divided by its name which hold smaller lists

The first is

```
list_1 = [('Tomato', 'red', 5)]
```

The second is

```
list 2 = [('Grape', 'green', 2), ('Grape', 'red', 2]
```

The third is

```
list 3 = [('Apple', 'white', 1), ('Apple', 'red', 1), ('Apple', 'green' 1)]
```

When i put it into array it to later inputted into multi bar stack

```
Tomato = np.array([list_1[0][2], list_2[0][2], list_3[0][2]])
Grape = np.array([list_1[1][2], list_2[1][2], list_3[1][2]])
Apple = np.array([list_1[2][2], list_2[2][2], list_3[2][2]])
```

The problem is that it says that list index is out of range which i know it is because my tomato only has one color when my array needs three.

But i need it because in case the person actually put 2 more colour, how do i tell my code "hey buddy can you just ignore it and make the empty part 0 for now?"

Another note: How do i make that its consistent some sort like all the color go into the same place

so it will turn into
The first will be `list_1 = [('Tomato', 'red', 5)]`

The second will be `list_2 = [('Grape', 'red', 2), ('Grape', 'green', 2]`

the third will be `list_3 = [('Apple', 'red', 1), ('Apple', 'green', 1), ('Apple', 'white' 1)]`

This is not yet important, i only need the first one, the second one is just my curiousity, thank you

Comment: Do you need to stick to NumPy? It looks like you have tabular data, for which there are better packages out there (`pandas`)?

Comment: "How do i make that its consistent some sort like all the color go into the same place": probably with a record array; the next step would be to use Pandas. Note that "in the same place" is more a of a human, output, problem than a code problem: the code should just check for the color, not rely on the ordering.

Comment: you can change it to pandas no prob

Comment: As @norok2 mentioned, I think its better to shift to pandas dataframe. You can name the columns as (Column1: Fruit name, Column2: Fruit Color, Column3: Quantity).

Comment: but can pandas be made into multi stack matplotlib bar?

Comment: Pandas can probably make you coffee if you ask kindly :-) Jokes aside, I think it has built-in functions for that and if that is not exactly what you need, you can still roll out your own plotting function from a pandas data source.

Comment: lol that is actually pretty funny, thanks